# making a hidden object game for android - need a way to define the "hid. objects" regardless of screen size

Tags: android

I was told that I could use some sort of "getEdge()" and, define a hidden object as n% from one edge and n% from another. Could someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

edit: This is a 2d game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I think you are asking is correct, then you just need to use dp units, or calculate a pixel/unit ratio if you are using OpenGL.

There is a fine article about the former here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: If there was a hat hidden in the image, how would I define it as a part of the image that could be touched(found)? (without OpenGl)

Comment: If evt has the position of a mouseclick on the screen, then you could simply do this `evt.x < hat.x && evt.x < hat.x + hat.width() && evt.y < hat.y && evt.y < hat.y + hat.height()`

Comment: Thanks again, Rasive. I think I've got it now thanks to your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have done this with a trick of stacking a mask made from a bitmap behind the real image. I can then color each object the exact same shape on the mask, and a different color each.  When the user clicks you get the pixel color from the mask, and use that color against an array of the objects to see what was selected. This gives you simple pixel level control.

The best part is, once you make the code to read the color, it is simple to trace the objects and stack the pictures to make many screens.